# Python QMessageBox new line '\n' and link broken

Tags: python, qmessagebox

I have a QMessageBox and want to create a link on a new line. I cannot get the link to work when I use \n

```
link = "www.google.com"
msg = "This works: <a href='%s'>Google</a>" % link
reply = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', msg, QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok)

msg = "This does not work: \n<a href='%s'>Google</a>" % link
reply = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', msg, QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok)
```

I would like to get the second example to work.

Answer (score 4):

If you use HTML formatting the newline character <del>has no special meaning - it's just whitespace as anything else, and is collapsed to a single space</del> actually, it does seem to throw off the HTML auto-detector, which falls back to plain text. Anyhow, to put your link on a separate line use the `<br>` line break tag, or put the two lines in different paragraphs using the `<p>` tag.

```
msg = "This works as well:<br><a href='%s'>Google</a>" % link
reply = QMessageBox.information(self, 'Message', msg, QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok)
```

[image: demo dialog with newline working]